# How to auto generate salesforce package.xml for incremental changes in Bitbucket?

Tags: continuous-integration

I am using Microsoft DevOps to deploying my changes to salesforce org and Bitbucket for versioning. Now, how can I auto-generate salesforce package.xml for all the incremental changes in Bitbucket so only the modified components get deployed?

Comment: What actual deployment tool are you using?

Comment: I am using Salesforce Ant migration tool which is also part of my repository.